# iOS, remove notification with app not running like gmail app

Tags: ios, notifications, push-notification

I was observing the behavior of the gmail iOS app. When I receive an email the app shows a notification. I have the app closed, it is not running.

But when I read the email on the pc, the notification disappears immediatly on the iPhone. How is it possible to reproduce this behavior in my app? How can I remotely clear the notifications?

Thanks

Comment: this is an interesting question, I'm not sure if can works, but just try to send a notification with badge = 0 and without the 'alert' and 'sound' objects in the notification dictionary, this should send a silent notification that will reset the badge value, let me know if this works

Comment: I was thinking at the same solution..I'll try and let you know..

Comment: @allemattio did you get it to work?

Comment: @BK I've never tryed to realize it, It was just a preliminary evaluation..sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever the Gmail server detects that the mail has been read a silent push notification with a badge number of 0 is sent to clear the badge value.

I wish that Facebook did that as well.